# Possible to make old vs M2E Magento plug-in work again?

Tags: magento, m2e-pro

I have a new version of Magento and M2E Pro, but I also have an old 2011 version on another computer. It has a function that I would like to use that the new version has lost (sad). When I try to use the old one I get an SSL error from eBay. Is there any possible work-around? Should the old version still function?

My old Magento version is 1.5.1.0. The old M2E Pro version is 5.0.0.base.

I am having a coder help me with this. He tells me that when M2E is trying to access this URL, https://ess-ua.com/accept.php, we get the SSL error.

Who knows, maybe it's something simple! Thanks! JP

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with your SSL certificate setup on the server, not Magento itself.  Remove the SSL certificate and reinstall it correctly.  If you are not sure how to do this, contact your server admin or host.